# Is there a safe way to cast float64 to int64 in Go?

Tags: go, casting, truncation

I am aware of the `int()` or `int64()` typecast functions, the Go provides.
Is there a safe way to cast `float64` to `int64` (*with truncation*,) given the largest representable 64-bit floating point number `math.MaxFloat64` is much larger than `math.MaxInt64`? A way, that triggers an overflow error?

Comment: You can check before the conversion whether the `float64` value is less than `MinInt64` or greater than `MaxInt64`. If so, the conversion will surely overflow.

Comment: @JimB you can compare to a `float64` value being closest to `MaxInt64`.

Comment: @icza: yeah true, I just meant it may be surprising since it's outside of `+/-1<<53`

Comment: Thank you very much! This conversation provides much insight and Jim's answer is very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *converting* (not casting or typecasting) from a `float64` to an `int64`, then you can compare the float value to the closest double precision integer values of `math.MaxInt64` and `math.MinInt64`. These numbers cannot be exactly stored in a `float64` value, however they will be stored as the next integer value above or below those:

```
float64(math.MaxInt64) // 9223372036854775808
float64(math.MinInt64) // -9223372036854775808
```

So as long as your `float64` value is between these two values, you know it can be converted to an `int64` without overflow.

Note however that if you are converting in the other direction, you cannot guarantee that a `float64` can accurately represent *all* `int64` values up to `MaxInt64`, since a double precision float point value only holds 52 bits of precision. In that case you must check that the `int64` value is between `-1<<53` and `1<<53`.

In either case you can handle larger values with the [`math/big`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big) package.